# It is possible to take incremental backup in Solr cloud cluster?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I want to take incremental backup for every commit for every collection in solr cloud cluster. It is possible to do?

Comment: Do you want to store the documents submitted for auditing, or do you want to perform an incremental backup of the files changed on each node? The first is probably better solved by submitting everything to a common endpoint and tracking it there, while the second will be harder (since merges can happen, and the new content are appended to the segment files). You can register [Eventlisteners](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updatehandlers-in-solrconfig.html#UpdateHandlersinSolrConfig-EventListeners), but these do not get a list of updated documents.

Comment: That being said - [using the CDCR could also help](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/cross-data-center-replication-cdcr.html), since it'll monitor the update log and send the updates to a secondary cluster as they happen. That way you'll have a second copy of everything ready (but this will also propagate deletes, so replication is not the same as a backup).

Comment: Yes, We want to perform an incremental backup of the files changed on each node @MatsLindh

Comment: The most direct way in that case is to run an incremental backup (using your regular infrastructure) on the data directory of your Solr installation on each node. Another option might be to use the replication api directly to get a list of modified files (that needs replication) and work with that, but I'm not familiar with any built-in solutions for Solr to do that.

Comment: Since Solr 8.9.0 incremental backups became available in Solr Cloud: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SOLR/SIP-12%3A+Incremental+Backup+and+Restore